# XSL to rename element based on attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to use XSL to transform an XML file and can't figure out how to rename an element as either the name or value of one of its attributes. I have found plenty of examples of converting attributes to elements and the other way around but I keep ending up with elements that are nested which I don't want. Here is an example:

Original XML:

`<row_item column="Hostname">HOST-A</row_item>`
  `<row_item column="IP Address">10.10.10.10</row_item>`

What I would like to output:

`<column>HOST-A</column>`

Or (preferred):

`<hostname>HOST-A</hostname>`

Comment: Could you explain more clearly? Is element's name in output XML dynamic? If so, is it based on `column` attribute value? What about 2nd `row_item`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="row_item[1]">
     <xsl:element name="{@column}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<rows>
    <row_item column="Hostname">HOST-A</row_item>
    <row_item column="IP Address">10.10.10.10</row_item>
</rows>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Hostname>HOST-A</Hostname>
```

**Explanation**:

Appropriate use of **[`xsl:element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl%3aelement)** and **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)**.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to rename some elements in a document is by using an identity transform and then adding some template for the elements you want to change.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- modify just the row_item with the specified attribute value -->
    <xsl:template match="row_item[@column='Hostname']">
        <hostname>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </hostname>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- the identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With an example xml of

```
<rows>
    <row_item column="Hostname">HOST-A</row_item>
    <row_item column="IP Address">10.10.10.10</row_item>
</rows>
```

This transforms to

```
<rows>
    <hostname>HOST-A</hostname>
    <row_item column="IP Address">10.10.10.10</row_item>
</rows>
```